# Evaluar booleano en un objeto [Nodejs]

Tags: javascript, nodejs, json, objeto

cómo puedo saber sí la propiedad booleana es verdadera o falsa?, tengo el objeto completo pero no sé como acceder a ella en específico para poder evaluarla.

```
let userData = await axios.get(`https://xxxx/v2/me`, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.xxxx}` } });
console.log(userData.data);

{
  id: 435156,
  phone: 'hidden',
  displayname: 'xxxx xxxx',
  image_url: 'https://xxxxx',
  new_image_url: 'https://xxxxx',
  'sudo?': true, // Está es la propiedad que quiero evaluar...
  xxxxxx: 6
}
```

He intentado con userData.data.sudo? pero devuelve error. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: *devuelve error* ¿Cuál error devuelve? La propiedad que muestras se llama `sudo?`, y al contener un carácter especial debes acceder a ella usando notación de corchete. Prueba así: `userData.data['sudo?']` y comenta el resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bien dice @MauricioContreras en el comentario de la pregunta, puedes acceder a una propiedad de este tipo mediante la [notación de corchetes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#notaci.c3.b3n_por_corchetes), entrecomillándola.

Aquí te dejo un snippet para que veas como efectivamente se puede usar como booleano de este modo:

```js
// let userData = await axios.get(`https://xxxx/v2/me`, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.xxxx}` } });

let userData = {}

userData.data = {
  id: 435156,
  phone: 'hidden',
  displayname: 'xxxx xxxx',
  image_url: 'https://xxxxx',
  new_image_url: 'https://xxxxx',
  'sudo?': true, // Está es la propiedad que quiero evaluar...
  xxxxxx: 6
}

console.log(userData.data['sudo?'])

if (userData.data['sudo?'] == true) {
  console.log('Verdadero')
} else {
  console.log('Falso')
}
```

El mérito no es mio, yo tan solo transcribo lo que ha dicho @MauricioContreras y amplio la información. Si el postea una respuesta ruego se acepte la suya, gracias.